# How to draw a star shape in ProcessingJS

Tags: processing, processing.js

Here is my current project code:

```
size(500,500);
background(255, 255, 255);

fill(250,0,0);
ellipse(150, 230, 100, 200);            
fill(10,0,0);
ellipse(180, 233, 30, 30);
fill(10,0,0);
ellipse(120, 233, 30, 30);
fill(250,250,250);
ellipse(120,233,10,20);
fill(250,250,250);
ellipse(180,233,10,20);

arc(150, 280, 60, 90, 0, PI/1);

fill(250,0,0);
rect(100,330,100,100);
fill(10,10,10);
rect(50,330,50,50);
fill(10,10,10);
rect(200,330,50,50);
fill(250,0,0);
rect(90,430,50,100);
fill(250,0,0);
rect(160,430,50,100);

fill(10,0,0);
triangle(60, 300, 101, 10, 50, 450);
```

Could someone please provide code on how to draw a basic 5 pointed star beside the deadpool character? (within the sized 500,500 dimensions)

Comment: Note that Processing.js was been archived 2 weeks ago (by me) and is no longer an active project. For new code, I recommend using p5js instead.

Answer (score 3):

See the processing documentation of [`PShapes`](https://processing.org/tutorials/pshape/) where there is a very simple implementation of a star shape in the Custom PShapes section.

See the [p5.js](https://p5js.org/) example which is very similar.
The code can be used in [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/), too. You have to change `createCanvas(500,500)` to `size(500,500)` and `push()` respectively `pop()` to `pushMatrix()` respectively `popMatrix()`:

```js
function setup() {    
    createCanvas(500,500);
}

function draw() {
    background(255, 255, 255);

    // star
    push();
    translate(280, 290); // center of the star
    fill(102);
    beginShape();
    vertex(0, -50);
    vertex(14, -20);
    vertex(47, -15);
    vertex(23, 7);
    vertex(29, 40);
    vertex(0, 25);
    vertex(-29, 40);
    vertex(-23, 7);
    vertex(-47, -15);
    vertex(-14, -20);
    endShape(CLOSE);
    translate(100, 100);
    pop();

    // character
    fill(250,0,0);
    ellipse(150, 230, 100, 200);  
    fill(10,0,0);
    ellipse(180, 233, 30, 30);
    fill(10,0,0);
    ellipse(120, 233, 30, 30);
    fill(250,250,250);
    ellipse(120,233,10,20);
    fill(250,250,250);
    ellipse(180,233,10,20);
    arc(150, 280, 60, 90, 0, PI/1);
    fill(250,0,0);
    rect(100,330,100,100);
    fill(10,10,10);
    rect(50,330,50,50);
    fill(10,10,10);
    rect(200,330,50,50);
    fill(250,0,0);
    rect(90,430,50,100);
    fill(250,0,0);
    rect(160,430,50,100);
    fill(10,0,0);
    triangle(60, 300, 101, 10, 50, 450);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
```